# Google maps rectangle selection tool: how to keep the rectangle displayed in keydragzoom library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, keydragzoom

With the keydragzoom library, you can mouse drag over a map to make rectangle selection, see this example: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/keydragzoom/2.0.9/examples/events.html

What I want is to use this as a selection tool, i.e. to select particular rectangle, and keep the rectangle (the selection) displayed. But the rectangle always dissapears after ending the mouse drag. Is there any way how to achieve this with this library?

I tried to set `noZoom` option to `true`, but it didn't help. I know I can draw my own rectangle, but it would require to handle situations when selecting a new rectangle, etc. So I would like to do it within this library.

Comment: Thank you Dr.Molle! BTW, did you just downvote my post? Why? because you wasted your answer?

Comment: @Dr.Molle, if I remember correctly, your solution just created a new rectangle in handler to `dragend` event... correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, I explicitly stated in my question that I'm not interested in the obvious workaround with creating my own rectangle.